# FontAwesome with CSS content does not work inside HR tag on IE or Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm using the freelancer theme for bootstrap. For this one, there is a nice star over an horizontal rule.

On FireFox and Chrome, it is working correctly.
On Internet Explorer and Edge, it does not work.

I changed all the hr.***** css rules to div.***** rules and change the pages according (changed the hr to div, and adding the closing tag). This version is working on the four major browsers.

I noticed that when removing:

```
top: -0.8em;
```

the icon was displaying below. It is like the HR does not allow to have something over it...

Can someone explain me why the HR CSS rules aren't working in IE/Edge ?

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmpPrO

```
body{
  background-color: #18BC9C;
}
div.star-light {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-top: solid 5px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 25px auto 30px;
}
div.star-light {
  border-color: white;
}
div.star-light:after{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d0";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.8em;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
}
div.star-light:after {
  background-color: #18BC9C;
  color: white;
}

hr.star-light {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-top: solid 5px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 25px auto 30px;
}
hr.star-light {
  border-color: white;
}
hr.star-light:after{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d0";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.8em;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
}
hr.star-light:after {
  background-color: #18BC9C;
  color: white;
}

.centered{
  text-align: center;
}
```

And the html:

```
<div class="centered">
  <p>Some text here</p>
  <div class="star-light"></div>
  <p>Some text after</p>
  <hr class="star-light">
  <p>Some text after after</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Void elements can't have content. So they can't have content in their `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements either. If something shows up in Firefox or Chrome, those browsers don't behave by the rules.